# I am running macOS high sierra with Xcode installed. when I tried to compile SoftEther VPN client from source, it gave me the linker error

Tags: macos, softether

I have tried to ask for help in both SoftEtherVPN github and their own forum, but not getting any reply, so I figure Unix or BSD expert here can chime in to shine a light on where went wrong in this linking stage. thanks.Cheers

The details of the makefile output is as below:

```
Jays-Mac-mini:SoftEtherVPN_Stable jayko$ make

cc tmp/as/vpnserver.a -O2 -fsigned-char -m64 -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -liconv
 -lreadline -lncurses -lz -lpcap -v -o bin/vpnserver/vpnserver

Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.x
ctoolchain/usr/bin
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/us
r/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -o bin/vpnse
rver/vpnserver tmp/as/vpnserver.a -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -liconv -lreadline 
-lncurses -lz -lpcap -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain
s/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a

ld: archive has no table of contents file 'tmp/as/vpnserver.a' for architecture x8
6_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [bin/vpnserver/vpnserver] Error 1

Jays-Mac-mini:SoftEtherVPN_Stable jayko$
```

Comment: [Look for problems in the configuration log `config.log`?](https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN_Stable/blob/master/BUILD_UNIX.TXT)

Comment: Thanks uprego.
- GNU Compiler Collectipon (gcc) and binary utilities.
- GNU Make (gmake).
- GNU C Library (glibc).      (gcc, gmake, glibc, I believe is included with the xcodes?)

- POSIX Threads (pthread).( is this already pre-installed with Xcodes?)
- OpenSSL (crypto, ssl).  (this is already came with the source, I also use brew to install it, so not an issue here)
- libiconv. readline. ncurses.     ( not sure how to check on my system if this has been installed for these three components)
The components required for compilation to be successful